# API Management always returning 200 instead of response

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have setup the policy below to try to forward my request to the backend in API Management

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="my site" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.Url.Path.Replace("/pml","/api"))" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I have 2 operations

Get Request - This is for Get Requests and has a Url /*
Post Request - This is for Post Requests and has a Url /*

Whenever I call this through Postman, I just get HTTP 200 responses rather than actual response data

What is wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

> I just get HTTP 200 responses rather than actual response data

AFAIK,
In the inbound - backend policies (re-write URL policy), the default response is `200 OK` only without the body content as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ReturnResponse) of Azure APIM advanced policies.

[image]

Body should be provided using context variable in return-response policy.

Comment: facing the same issue backend call is not getting triggered. Any input?

Comment: What is your scenario, what you're trying to achieve, what error you're getting? - Could you provide details in a new question.

Comment: I have API which calls backend azure api. I recently update response for error code 500 and deployed code. It is not hitting backend at all and giving 200 from api gateway itself.
Here is a question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725328/api-management-not-triggering-backend-call-to-function-app